# LSI MegaRaid live conversion from RAID 6 to RAID 0+1

Tags: raid, lsi, megaraid

I've currently got a lovely working server that has an LSI 9265-8i RAID card in it with 4x1TB RE4 drives, also running CacheCade Pro 2.0 with 2x180GB SSDs in RAID1. I currently have the main array running on RAID6, as much as I like it. I think running RAID 0+1 would be a better choice for the speed and making the server more responsive. Is there a way to 'migrate' my array from '6 to '0+1 without a full backup and restore (which I'd take a full backup anyway if all went wrong)?

The total available space will be the same (2TB) but I'm guessing my potential reliability will go down a little (if 2 drives fail simultaneously on the same stripe opposed to any 2 drives failing). Can anyone shed some more light on the subject please?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You mean, RAID 1+0? See: http://serverfault.com/a/339214/13325

Answer (score 0):

When we researched a similar problem using an LSi 9271-8i, there wasn't a method of accomplishing this; if there were, I'd imagine it would be the kind of thing that would take an incredible amount of time as well.

And yes, you'll definitely notice a read/write speed increase changing to RAID10, but your reliability will effectively drop to 1 drive failure tolerated, as opposed to your current 2 drive in RAID6.

Comment: You can lose two drives in a 4-disk RAID 1+0.

Comment: To @ewwhite, yes you can lose two drives if they're the right drives (ie. both of one parity stripe dies).  You should assume the worst in these kind of situations, not the best.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such method to convert a RAID6 into a RAID10 on LSI. You have to backup, recreate your RAID and restore the data.

As jski noted, your reliability will drop, while your speed will increase.